# Webpack plugin v5 existsAt doesn't exist in compilation object

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4, webpack-plugin

I'm upgrading a webpack plugin from v4 to v5. Part of my plugin used to read the `compilation.assets` object to figure out the generated asset's absolute path to do some calculation.

But each asset in v5 now only contains the `SizeOnlySource` object, which looks like this

```
{ _size: 840893 }
```

A subset of my plugin looks like this

```
compiler.hooks.afterEmit.tap('my-plugin', (compilation, callback) => {
    Object.keys(compilation.assets).forEach((filename) => {
      const asset = compilation.assets[filename];
      const absolutePath = asset.existsAt;
      // Do stuff ...
```

`absolutePath` returns be `undefined` in this case. My question is, what is the new way to access the absolute path of my file?

For reference I did look around but only information I could find was this issue that was closed immediately https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/12313

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it could help you somehow but try accessing the compilation.assetsInfo instead:

```
    new Map(compilation.assetsInfo).forEach(function(val, key) { 
        console.log('KEY: ' + key + ' -- VAL: ' + val.sourceFilename)
    });
```

Im running through some issues like yours.

Comment: Sorry doesn't help much. There's more info in `assetsInfo` but it's actually missing `sourceFilename`. The properties available are `immutable`, `contenthash`, `javascriptModule`, `minimized`, `size`